# How to calculate the threshold for gate fidelity?

Tags: error-correction, fidelity

I've been interested in gate fidelity lately.

In the meantime, I came up with a specific example. Let's think about the encoding of situation $\alpha_0 |0\rangle + \alpha_1 |1\rangle \rightarrow \alpha_0 |000\rangle + \alpha_1 |111\rangle$, and implement a circuit that can correct the case where there is an error in one bit out of three qubits.
That is, consider a quantum error correction.

In that time, what is the threshold for gate fidelity at which error correction stops (or becomes meaningless)?

I think fidelity is simply a connection between the ideal and the realistic, but when I try to think of it as a concrete example, it is difficult to figure out how to calculate it.
(I know the formula for calculating fidelity.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, take the case without encoding. Let there be an $X$ error with probability $p$, so the output state is
$$
\rho=(1-p)|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|+pX|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|X.
$$
Normally, I would just talk about the probability of an error (it lets you avoid some of the averaging I'm about to do), but we can talk about fidelity if you want.
$$
F=\langle\psi|\rho|\psi\rangle=1-p+p|\langle\psi|X|\psi\rangle|^2
$$
To get just a single number, you might average over all possible initial states $|\psi\rangle$. You'll find that
$$
\bar F=1-\gamma p
$$
for some positive value $\gamma$ that is not so important to calculate right now.

By comparison, consider the encoded qubit going through the error channel. If
$$
|\Psi\rangle=\alpha_0|000\rangle+\alpha_1|111\rangle,
$$
then
$$
\rho_2=(1-p)^3|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|+(1-p)^2p(X_1|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|X_1+X_2|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|X_2+X_3|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|X_3)+(1-p)p^2X_1X_2|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|X_1X_2+\ldots+p^3X_1X_2X_3|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|X_1X_2X_3.
$$
If you error correct this, it will succeed so long as there's no more than one error
$$
\rho_2\rightarrow (1-p)^2(1+2p)|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|+p^2(3-2p)X_1X_2X_3|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|X_1X_2X_3
$$
which will decode to
$$
(1-p)^2(1+2p)|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|+p^2(3-2p)X|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|X
$$
and hence have fidelity
$$
\bar F=1-\gamma p^2(3-2p).
$$

This fidelity is better than the fidelity from no encoding provided
$$
p^2(3-2p)<p.
$$
This is fulfilled for $0<p<\frac12$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, using the assumption that there are no more than two errors, terms with two errors disappear, but why do you consider probabilities?

Comment: What do you understand by "threshold" if it's not a threshold probability?

Comment: I know that threshold is probability. I mean when calculating $\rho_2$, the assumption that there were no more than two errors was used. And after correcting the error, I thought that the probabilities of the term with two errors would disappear and be computed. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, that's not the assumption I used to calculate $\rho_2$. My assumption was that each qubit suffers a bit-flip with probability $p$. So, there's a probability $p^3$ that 3 errors happen. When you later apply error correction, all states are mapped to the closest logical state. In the case of 2 errors, the closest logical state is the one with 3 $X$ errors, so that's what they get mapped to.